# phone plugged to computer, ring in computer sound system

Tags: usb

I usually keep my phone plugged by usb to my computer.

But when someone call me, I'd like to have the ringtone going to the computer, and then to the computer sound system (like, the wireless headphone I'm wearing all day long).

I'm looking for a Windows or Linux solution